# Python Selenium Click to Open Chrome Print Dialog Hangs

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have a Chrome window with a print button that I am navigating with Selenium. I click the button like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('print_button_id').click()
```

The click is successful, because the Chrome print dialog box opens:

[image]

However, no code after the click runs, and it appears to hang until I manually click `Cancel` on the print dialog. I tried using other methods of clicking (e.g. `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`), but the same result occurs.

The same thing occurs when I use JavaScript to execute the print command:

```
driver.execute_script("window.print()")
```

That line of code hangs until I manually interact with the print dialog. This prevents me from automatically clicking the Print button on the print dialog with ActionChains.

Why is the click hanging, despite successfully opening the Chrome print dialog?

Comment: not sure what more details I could provide - it's a pretty simple issue.

Comment: That's a modal dialog that's outside of the browser. You cannot interact with it using Selenium.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium interacts with browser and this dialog box is not a part of browser because of which nothing is happening in here.

Comment: Could be a good idea give the answer to the problema instead just say that.